# Kentico CMSListMenu not displaying enough levels of the tree?

Tags: kentico

I have a kentico CMSListMenu which contains 4 levels at it deepest, i want to display the menu as a nested list down the left hand side of my content, this works fine for 3 levels but i cant get the 4th level to display.

I have this working on another site using the exact same code so i must be missing something, these are the menu expressions i have tried using:

```
<cc1:CMSListMenu ID="CMSTreeMenu1" runat="server" Path="/{0}/{1}/{2}/%" DisplayHighlightedItemAsLink="True" DisplayOnlySelectedPath="true" Indentation="0"  MaxRelativeLevel="5" /></cc1:cmslistmenu>

<cc1:CMSListMenu ID="CMSTreeMenu1" runat="server" Path="/Products---Solutions/%" DisplayHighlightedItemAsLink="True" DisplayOnlySelectedPath="true" Indentation="0"  MaxRelativeLevel="5" /></cc1:cmslistmenu>
```

do i need to set this somewhere else? perhaps somewhere inside of kentico to output so many levels down?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has been causing me problems for days

Comment: You mention it has 4 levels at it's deepest. Is that from the root of the site, or from the path you have specified? Because you're starting the Path in a nested directory.

Comment: my menu goes

Root/
     Products/
              product name/
                          knowledge resource/
                                            literature

I cannot get the literature page to display with the above controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the CMS List Menu only displays cms.Page (Menu Item) documents by default.  If you're trying to display other types of documents, make sure you set that in the menu properties.

Comment: Thanks for your help, all my menu items are cms.Page but they still dont show up

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `DisplayOnlySelectedPath="false"` to see if it displays everything as you expect it to under the menu.